# how to iterate a datafrme to do "prallel" join in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe contains different toxic combination of permissions, I want to iterate toxic combination of permissions dataframe so that I can join another table on the filtered toxic user dataframe, to gain more information on the person's information and department information

Right now I am just `for row in df_toxic_perms_combinations.rdd.collect` more in a Pandas way to solve the problem, But I read about it and it may be slow and not utilizing the distributed concept. So I really want to use map() or foreach() to solve it.

So now I am trying to do a

```py
toxic_perms_df.rdd.foreach(lambda x: permissions_checking_df.filter(
        (array_contains(permissions_checking_df.perm_type_list, x.toxic1))&(array_contains(permissions_checking_df.perm_type_list, x.toxic2))&(array_contains(permissions_checking_df.perm_type_list, x.toxic3))&(array_contains(permissions_checking_df.perm_type_list, x.toxic3))
        ))
```

I am getting

> Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

> PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

What I am doing wrong or is there a better way to perform this?